# ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES error when loading a local webpage PySide2, QUrl, and QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyside2, qtwebengine, qurl

I am receiving a ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES while trying to load a local SQL website into a PySide2 application. Any solution to this?

I have tried using https and http, as well as using reports = QUrl.fromUserInput("") with  replaced with the URL to try to force it to resolve the URL. No luck.